# L Limit screw can get front derailleur close enough

Tags: derailleur-front

I am following the instructions on here:

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment

And they say:

"Sight gap between inner chain plate and inner cage plate. Only a small gap should be visible, about 1/16″ or 1mm, about the thickness of a dime."

"If the gap appears larger than 1mm at its widest point, tighten the L-screw, in small increments, until the gap closes."

But I've tightened the L screw all the way and there is still a massive gap....? (I can make the gap larger by loosening it but obviously that's not what I want)

What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I was missing was that the screw wasn't fully tightened but it was impossible to tighten the screw whilst the derailleur was against the limit and the cable was tight. Pulling the cable to move the derailleur and tightening the screw at the same time worked fine. Totally slack cable would have been fine as well I think.

Comment: Why was the cable tight when the derailleur was at the low limit? That should only be an issue for the high limit, no?

Comment: Because the tension was set wrong before. If I had just totally undone the cable clamp bolt it would have been OK. Shifting to the lowest cog made the cable slack as they describe, but trying to move it outward with the L Screw made it tight again, to the point that I could no longer screw the screw.